# Debugging does not step into function Spring REST Service @Controller with curl

Tags: spring, rest, curl

I've a Spring Version: 3.6.3.RELEASE Project with a REST Service and I want to debug the @RequestMapping @Controller class by initiating a request throug curl.
 Ive set debugging Breakepoints in the function of the @RequestMapping

and Ive started the project in debug mode ....
and everything is starting up fine .....

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.0.1.RELEASE)

2015-03-08 11:38:00.288  INFO 4252 --- [           main] com.pekam.Application                    : Starting Application on KABUL with PID 4252 (C:\Users\pk\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\MyRestDataRepository\target\classes started by pk)
2015-03-08 11:38:00.333  INFO 4252 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6b6776cb: startup date [Sun Mar 08 11:38:00 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-03-08 11:38:00.682  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2015-03-08 11:38:01.140  INFO 4252 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3fc9350d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-03-08 11:38:01.162  INFO 4252 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-03-08 11:38:01.172  INFO 4252 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-03-08 11:38:01.179  INFO 4252 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-03-08 11:38:01.380  INFO 4252 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8080
2015-03-08 11:38:01.523  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-03-08 11:38:01.523  INFO 4252 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
2015-03-08 11:38:01.640  INFO 4252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-03-08 11:38:01.640  INFO 4252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1310 ms
2015-03-08 11:38:02.103  INFO 4252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-03-08 11:38:02.105  INFO 4252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-03-08 11:38:02.353  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: org.h2.Driver
2015-03-08 11:38:02.353  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
2015-03-08 11:38:02.353  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2015-03-08 11:38:02.493  INFO 4252 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-03-08 11:38:02.514  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2015-03-08 11:38:02.590  INFO 4252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
2015-03-08 11:38:02.592  INFO 4252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-03-08 11:38:02.594  INFO 4252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-03-08 11:38:02.795  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
2015-03-08 11:38:03.064  INFO 4252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2015-03-08 11:38:03.181  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2015-03-08 11:38:03.510  INFO 4252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2015-03-08 11:38:03.510  INFO 4252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2015-03-08 11:38:03.516  INFO 4252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000396: Updating schema
2015-03-08 11:38:03.533  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000261: Table found: test.tblgps
2015-03-08 11:38:03.533  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000037: Columns: [date, descr, provider, lon, id, deviceid, userid, lat]
2015-03-08 11:38:03.533  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
2015-03-08 11:38:03.533  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
2015-03-08 11:38:03.534  INFO 4252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
2015-03-08 11:38:03.941  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-03-08 11:38:04.064  INFO 4252 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/TblGps/List/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.List<com.pekam.TblGps> com.pekam.TblGpsController.findAll()
2015-03-08 11:38:04.064  INFO 4252 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/TblGps/get],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.pekam.TblGps com.pekam.TblGpsController.findById(long)
2015-03-08 11:38:04.064  INFO 4252 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/TblGps/update3/],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[*/*],produces=[application/json || */*],custom=[]}" onto public com.pekam.TblGps com.pekam.TblGpsController.post1(com.pekam.TblGps)
2015-03-08 11:38:04.064  INFO 4252 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/TblGps/update],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[*/*],produces=[*/*],custom=[]}" onto public com.pekam.TblGps com.pekam.TblGpsController.post(com.pekam.TblGps)
2015-03-08 11:38:04.065  INFO 4252 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/*],methods=[GET || POST || DELETE || PUT || HEAD],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.pekam.TblGpsController.allFallback()
2015-03-08 11:38:04.065  INFO 4252 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/TblGps/update2/],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[*/*],produces=[*/*],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.pekam.TblGpsController.post2(java.lang.String)
2015-03-08 11:38:04.093  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-03-08 11:38:04.094  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-03-08 11:38:04.161  INFO 4252 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in restResponseEntityExceptionHandler
2015-03-08 11:38:04.345  INFO 4252 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-03-08 11:38:04.378  INFO 4252 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080/http
2015-03-08 11:38:04.380  INFO 4252 --- [           main] com.pekam.Application                    : Started Application in 4.383 seconds (JVM running for 4.904)
```

but when i execute the Request with curl  the debuger does not step into the function.

```
 C:\Users\pk>curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d {"date":1425811355985,"de
    scr":null,"deviceID":"1","provider":"fused","id":0,"lat":4.0,"userid":1,"lon":4.
    0} http://127.0.0.1:8080/TblGps/update
```

The curl output is: just nothing

It seems linke the debugger is not properly attached to the process but when i change my curl request to bad mapping entry  STS is showing me the errors on the console debugging windows.

any Ideas appreciated !!

code

```
@Controller
public class TblGpsController {

     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TblGpsController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "*", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST ,RequestMethod.DELETE,RequestMethod.PUT,RequestMethod.HEAD })
@ResponseBody
public String allFallback() {
    return "Fallback for All Requests";
}

      @RequestMapping(value="/TblGps/update", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE,produces= MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
      @ResponseBody public TblGps post(@RequestParam("object") TblGps gps){

        return Application.DataRepository.save(gps);
  }
```

Comment: On Windows I need to add `"` double quotes around the JSON, as well as escaping _all_ the inner quotes `\"`. On UNIX systems, you can try and wrap the JSON in single quotes `'`. I don't think the double quote escaping is needed

Comment: Just wanted to find out if it helped.

Comment: You were right  it was  the problem with the quotes in windows!!! Now I changed my curl command to curl -v  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @json.txt http://127.0
.0.1:8080/TblGps/update
an put my json data in a file ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use @RequestParam annotation if you are posting JSON data. Its annotation that needs to be used if you want to parse the data in the request body which in your case is json data sent as post.

```
@ResponseBody public TblGps post(@RequestBody TblGps gps){

        return Application.DataRepository.save(gps);
  }
```

Comment: the curl command was wrong with the quotes on windows and of course you were right with the missing @RequestBody. thanks for your help!